# Force change in aspect ratio of Inset image

Tags: graphics, image

I have an image that I want to place in the background of a plot and stretch it to cover the entire plot area. However, the aspect ratio of the image does not match the aspect ratio of the plot, and `Inset` refuses to stretch the image.

```
image = Image@Map[ColorData["SunsetColors"], 
   Table[(y - x^2 + 1)/2, {y, Reverse@Range[0, 1, 0.02]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}], {2}];
ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourShading -> None, 
 Prolog -> Inset[image, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}]]
```

[image]

The `Inset` documentation states:

> - If size is given as $\{w,h\}$, then any object $\mathit{obj}$ whose aspect ratio is not fixed will be horizontally or vertically stretched so as to fit exactly in a $w\times h$ rectangle.
> - If $\mathit{obj}$ is an object with fixed aspect ratio, then blank space will be left equally on both sides if there is a direction where the object would have to be stretched in order to fit exactly.

Evidently `Inset` thinks the image is an object with fixed aspect ratio. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining `Image` and `Graphics` require `Image` to be converted to `Raster` which can be made by `Show[image]`. The second argument of `Raster` allows to stretch the image to the full plot range area by using `Scaled` coordinates:

```
image = Image@Map[ColorData["SunsetColors"], 
    Table[(y - x^2 + 1)/2, {y, Reverse@Range[0, 1, 0.02]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}], {2}];

pl1 = ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourShading -> None, 
 Prolog ->Raster[Show[image][[1, 1]], {Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}]}]]
```

> [image: plot1]

You can also use explicit coordinates:

```
pl2 = ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourShading -> None, 
 Prolog -> Raster[Show[image][[1, 1]], {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]]
```

> [image: plot2]

Instead of `Show[image][[1, 1]]` one can use `ImageData[image, DataReversed -> True]` with the same effect.

You can also achieve the same effect by setting `AspectRatio -> Full` for the image inside of the `Inset`:

```
pl3 = ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourShading -> None, 
  Prolog -> Inset[Show[image, AspectRatio -> Full], 
    Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled@1]]
pl4 = ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourShading -> None, 
  Prolog -> Inset[Show[image, AspectRatio -> Full], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}]]
```

The results are exactly identical in rendering:

```
Image[pl1] === Image[pl3]
Image[pl2] === Image[pl4]
```

> ```
> True
>
> True
> ```

Comment: Your background image is rotated.

Comment: @paw Thanks, fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the help clearly indicates that it won't stretch it automatically.  And I don't know of any sneaky way of making it do so.  But you could write a helper function to stretch it for you:

```
Clear[insetImage];
insetImage[image_Image, pos_, opos_, size : {w_, h_}] :=
  Module[{a, b},
   {a, b} = ImageDimensions@image;
   Inset[ImageResize[image, If[w <= h, a {1, h/w}, b {w/h, 1}]], pos, opos, size]
   ];
```

Now just use `insetImage` instead of `Inset` and it should magically do what you want.

```
ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourShading -> None, 
   Prolog -> insetImage[image, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, #]] & /@ {{0.3, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.7}, {1, 0.5}, {1, 1}}
```

[image: stretch]

Answer (score 1):

Is the code you posted just a working example?

You could get this plot much simpler:

```
DensityPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 9]
```

[image]

The alternative is to rescale the image manually.

```
image = Image@
   Map[ColorData["SunsetColors"], 
     Table[(y - x^2 + 1)/2, {y, Reverse@Range[0, 1, 0.02]}, {x, 0, 1, 
       0.01}], {2}];
image = ImageResize[image, {#1, 2*#2 - 1}] & @@ ImageDimensions@image;
ContourPlot[y - x^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourShading -> None, 
   Prolog -> Inset[image, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's just an example; my actual plots are more complicated. I don't want to use `DensityPlot` because if you export as PDF you can see ugly tessellation boundaries. `ImageResize` could work in a pinch, but I'm also curious if I can get Mathematica to just stretch the existing image.