# How do I change the size of an imported picture in an animation?

Tags: image, animation, size

My code right now plots a function, and animates an image moving along the curve of the function. I want to reduce the size of the image for this animation but I can't figure out how. If I try to change

```
image = Import["image.png"]
```

to

```
image = Import["image.png",ImageSize -> Tiny]
```

it just makes the image blurry in the animation. This is the animation code:

```
Animate[Plot[{f[z]}, {z, 0, 50}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 10}}, 
  Epilog -> Inset[image, {x, f[x]}]], {x, 
  0, 30}]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Just set the image size to a somewhat larger value.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Although this is dealing with an image, the actual focus lies on the `Inset`, which is discussed here:[Scale Insetted Characters to Plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4374/scale-insetted-characters-to-plot)

Comment: @Jens I think the selected duplicate is poor.  Chat link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/20126893#20126893

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(73838)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73838/121).  Related: [(59235)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59235/121), [(73522)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73522/121)

Answer (score 5):

Use the fourth parameter of [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html):

[image]

```
f = Sin[#] + 5 &;
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

Animate[Plot[{f[z]}, {z, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 10}}, 
  Epilog -> Inset[image, {x, f[x]}, Automatic, 10]], {x, 0, 30}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Show` with the option `ImageSize`:

```
image = Show[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], ImageSize -> 40];
f = 5 + Sin[#] + Sin[Sqrt[2] #] &;

Animate[Plot[{f[z]}, {z, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 10}}, 
  Epilog -> Inset[image, {x, f[x]}]], {x, 0, 50}]
```

[image]